# Rails checkbox change in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

I am total beginner in rails, trying to get some stuff together. I was browsing Stack Overflow about this issue for a while, but none of the advised stuff worked (and since I know Rails and Ruby are changing a lot - I guess it is normal).

So, the thing is - I want to create AJAX call when I click the checkbox, and later, change one boolean-type value in DB. My "object" is task and attribute is "status".

I tried:

```
<div class="header">  
<% form_for @task, :id => "status" do |f| %>  
<label><%= f.check_box :called, :onclick => "$('#status').submit()" %></label>  
<% end %>  
</div>
```

But it complains about `undefined method model_name for NilClass:Class`.
Can you please maybe help with this?

Thank you very much.

---

EDIT:

Hmm, still that nasty error. Maybe the problem is in surroundings?

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
<div class="post" id="<%= task.id =%>">
<div class="header"><%= form_for(@task, :id => "status", :remote => true) do |f| %>
<label>
<%= f.check_box :called %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %> <span class="title"><%= task.title =%></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Do you have `@task = Task.new` in your controller?

Comment: Yes, I do have it there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem would seem to be that @task is nil.
Perhaps copy and paste the controller code.

I would normally include a non-nil @task in both the "new" and "edit" actions

```
def new
  @task = Task.new
end

def create
  @task = Task.new(params[:task])
  ...
end

def edit
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
end
```

I'm guessing in this example @task is nil.

---

edit: adding a better way to do the form submit.

Also I would suggest not using the :on_click html attribute.
in particular, this will not send an ajax submit.

I suggest you use the jquery rails helpers to make it sent via ajax.
Namely add the :remote => true param to form_for

```
<% form_for(@task, :id => "status", :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

Also in Rails >3 you should use the `<%=` for this type of tag.

```
<%= form_for(@task, :id => "status", :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

Lets rewrite it all

```
<%= form_for(@task, :id => "status", :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :called %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<script>
  jQuery(function($){
    // grab the form in this closure;
    var form = $("form#status");

    // hide the submit button
    form.find("input[type=submit]").hide();

    // set the click handler
    $("#task_called").click(function(){
      form.submit();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my controller contains everything you written.

Comment: the form_for bit should be in the associated view, not in the controller - based on the context of previous descriptions, I'm inclined to say new.html.erb in the folder that matches the name of your controller in /views

Comment: Hmm, still that nasty error. Maybe the problem is in surroundings?

Answer (score 1):

You should edit your question not post an answer with edits :)

Well, answer lies there:

```
1 <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
2 <div class="post" id="<%= task.id =%>">
3 <div class="header"><%= form_for(@task, :id => "status", :remote => true) do |f| %>
4 <label>
5 <%= f.check_box :called %>
```

Line 1 you loop `@tasks` and create `task`.

But line 3 you call `@task` instead of  `task`

Comment: So, I tried to swap `@task` for task in form definition, but now I get `undefined method 'called' for #<Task:0x103cc1538>`. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @mrkva: It simply means the `tables` column has no `:called` row. Did you migrate the db? (Basically, your error now lies line 5)